# Is it valid to build a binomial hierarchical model with skewed observations between random effect levels?

Tags: multilevel-analysis, generalized-additive-model, nested-data

I am trying to model the relationship between vegetation growth and insect outbreaks (binomial: 0=non-outbreak, 1 = outbreak) by bioregion and season. To do this, I am constructing a hierarchical GAM (a la [Pedersen et al. 2019](https://peerj.com/articles/6876/)).

The issue I am thinking about is that my observations are not equally distributed between bioregions and seasons. In fact it is a very right tail skewed distribution with many bioregions (29 total). Further, the 1s and 0s are not distributed evenly. There are bioregions and seasons that dont have 1s and only 0s (and vice versa). Specifying a hierarchy where some of the random effect levels have few to no observations seems like a big issue, however I would like to keep this data in for estimating the global smoother trend.

Here is my question: **Is it valid to build a hierarchical model with skewed observations between random effect levels?** To give an example of what my data looks like, I have drawn a quick histogram with bioregions (broken into 0 and 1) below. This shows only bioregions and not seasons, but as you can imagine, the unequal distribution becomes worse when you break each bioregion into seasons.

[image]

Comment: Yes, it is valid. Ultimately the random effect structure will estimate a standard deviation. I would be more worried about potentially under-fitting within certain regions.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the response!